# Why are 'end' & 'else' statement not counted in code coverage during rspec testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, simplecov

I am using simplecov gem to view test coverage. In following image, I can see two statements `else` and `end` are in white colour.
Are these lines not counted in test coverage? If yes, what can be done to include such statements ?
[image: SimpleCov code coverage image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These aren't lines of code. You can't test them, so simplecov ignores them.

Your `if` has been covered, so because of that we assume that the end has been covered. The `else` is also not covered, but we only care that the code inside that branch has been covered.

SimpleCov should untested code as a red line and untestable code as grey. The code above has 100% test coverage, so don't worry.